# /me/memberOf to show groups a user is a "nested" member of

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to tidy up the menus in an app. For example, I've got a link `A` that requires a user be part of a security group called `graphsec_A`.

It's a Node app, so I make a call to `/me/memberOf` and get back an array of objects which I can filter to see if `displayName` equals `graphsec_A`.

If I add the user directly to a Group, it works when I check this way. In my case however, I have a whole department I want to add to the Group (along with some others depts and individuals). When I add a Group to `graphsec_A`, that membership isn't returned in `/me/memberOf`.

I've tried messing around with `$expand`, but I can't seem to get it to work but showing the extended version of all the Groups a user is a member of.

Any way to make this work without having to add everyone individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`/checkMemberGroups`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_checkmembergroups). Unlike `/memberOf`, the `/checkMemberGroups` method is transitive; meaning it checks both for direct and indirect membership in a Group.

You can check up to 20 groups at a time by issuing a `POST` to `/v1.0/me/checkMemberGroups` with a list of Group ID's in the body:

```
{
  "groupIds": [
    "group1-id", "group2-id", ...
  ]
}
```

In your scenario, you would send the Groups your application is interested in. The API will return back the subset of your list that the current user belongs to.

Comment: Thanks... I was afraid of that! Built the flow around /memberOf mapped into an Array of displayNames, but I guess I'll have to figure out some middleware now to store and compare the groups based on their ID's.

Comment: You may not need any middleware. You can make a request to Groups filtered by the `displayName(s)` you want and selecting just the `id` fields. Take the output of that call to build your `/checkMemberGroups`. You'll need two separate calls but you shouldn't require any additional data points beyond the `displayName` you have today.

Comment: Thanks very much for this - I'm going to play around getting the logic right, but testing quickly on the graph explorer looks like it will do what I'm look for. Cheers!